# Number margin Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I don't think the title makes much sense, but I wouldn't really know what to call it.

You know that number margin thing, that Python Idle has? It has a number on each line.. How would I set that in VS?

Sorry for the really really really stupid question. Ive done some research and I keep finding programs to count words and stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to options -> text editor -> general and enable line numbes

Answer (score 1):

Type `Line Numbers` in the Quick Launch box on the top right and it will take you to the right Options page.